# Run ansible commands in mixed environment

Tags: ansible

I want to run ansible from localhost and for one command i want to execute in  different host? How to run single ansible role on two different machine.

My playbook looks like

```
hosts: localhost
gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
  - some_role
```

*role/some_role* playbook contains one command which needs to run on master node of k8s server. How do we run this in playbook?

In short **I don't want to run on list of server, I want to run set of command on one server and other command on other server**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) in the role

Example (*roles/some_role/tasks/main.yml*):

```
---
- shell: hostnamectl
- shell: hostnamectl
  delegate_to: otherhost
```

For the playbook which you specified - if *some_role* tasks will contain above, first task will run on *localhost* and second on *otherhost* (*otherhost* must also be in your inventory)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below:
Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
  - some_role
- hosts: serverA
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
  - some_role
```

Comment: I don't want to run on list of server, I want to run set of command on one server and other command on other server.

Comment: Then you can run it twice. Updated answer.

Comment: sorry that's not what i am looking for